# I am not able to run my program even though it is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a program to parse json files and get the list of requests and their response.

```
import os
import json
import shutil

def generateReport(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        data=f.load(json)
    requestList=[x['request'] for x in data['log']['entries'] if x['_resourceType']=='xhr']
    responsList=[x['response'] for x in data['log']['entries'] if x['_resourceType']=='xhr']
    
    return (requestList,responsList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listOfFiles = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    print(listOfFiles)
    if not os.path.exists("Reports"):
        os.mkdir('Reports')
    pair=[]
    for eachfile in listOfFiles:
        if eachfile.endswith('.har') :
            newFileName = newFileName.split('.')
            newFileName = '.'.join(newFileName[:-1])+'.json'
            os.rename(eachfile, newFileName)
            requestList,responsList = generateReport(newFileName)
        for i in len(requestList):
            pair.append([requestList[i]['method']+' '+requestList[i]['url'],responsList[i]['status']+' '+responsList['statusText']])
    reportFile = newFileName+'Report.txt'
    o = open(reportFile,'w')
    o.writelines(pair)
    shutil.move(os.getcwd()+'\\'+reportFile,os.getcwd()+'\\Reports\\'+fileNameToSave)
```

but i am always getting this error in command line when i run `python3 requestList.py`

```
python3 requestList.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requestList.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.mkdir('Reports')
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'Reports'
```

Even though i have given a check, the program is failing at the mkdir part. So i put a print statement above it to check if it is working fine there but event that is not getting executed.

Comment: Use a try block for checking if the file exists.

Comment: Where are you defining `fileNameToSave`? It seems theres no variable with that name and so the name of the file is set as `Reports` that already exists like the error suggests.

Comment: This is not the code you are running. I counted the lines, and the `os.mkdir` is on line 17 of the code you posted but the error message says that it is line 16.

Comment: Probably you are running an outdated version of the code that does not have the `if` check? The fact that your `print` statement is not executed further suggests this. (Although without both the `if` _and_ the `print` line the error should be on line 15...)

Comment: thanks...there were multiple error in the program but the reason it was behaving wierd because i had two copies of the same program in my pc and i was making corrections to one of them but executing the other one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.mkdir() can be used only once in a program. Once you use the fore coming statement

```
os.mkdir('Reports')
```

the directory is created. Hence, the next time when try to execute that statement, the interpreter shows error as it cannot create another directory with the same name 'Reports'

Try removing that statement. You'll get the desired output, I suppose